# Eu perco o histórico de commits se trocar a remote branch?

Tags: git, github

Se trocar a remote do Git eu acabo perdendo o histórico de commit para a nova remote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não - quando você sobe um branch em um remote, todo o histórico de commits daquele branch vai junto.

A única coisa é que se você tem vários branches em um remote, tem que subir todos no novo remote para ter uma réplica exata - mas como a grande maioria dos projetos tem apenas um branch principal, e as vezes um ou dois auxiliares que realmente são importantes para a história toda do projeto, basta subir esses.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação